# Lost data in sqlite file when using moveItemAtURL

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I have a chat app with existing sqlite file, now I create a Notification Service Extension and need to share that sqlite file with NSE, so I move existing sqlite to public location with the following code:

```
NSURL *source = [[Utils applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"file_name.sqlite"];
    NSURL *destination = [[Utils applicationDocumentsDirectoryPublic] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"file_name.sqlite"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:source.path]) {
        BOOL isSuccess = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:source toURL:destination error:nil];
        if(isSuccess) {
            NSLog(@"movingCoreData success");
        } 
    }



 + (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    NSURL *path = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];

    return path;
}
+ (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectoryPublic {
    NSURL *path = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:APP_GROUP];

    return path;
}
```

The sqlite file move success, but some data is lost, and it's not happend for all user (I tried with account A and account B, account A is lost half data (almost is group chat) while account B is fine. And when I fetch data in NSE, it's not return data for me, I see a warning:

```
CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'Conversation' for entity 'Conversation'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
```

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a result of CoreData using SQLite’s WAL mode by default, which means many of the transactions for the database are stored in a separate file (“...sqlite-wal”).  Your copy process does not copy this file, so the transactions go missing.

You could just add another NSFileManager operation to move the WAL file, but as set out in this [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1809/_index.html) it is better to use NSPersistentStoreCoordinator’s `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:` method.

Comment: Thanks, I open app folder and realized there is 2 more files, wal and shm file. I moved them all and no more losing data. I didn't try migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error: yet, will try later